# Symfony2/Doctrine2 - Escaping special char in password

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I escape a password I'm using for a database connection via Doctrine?

In my password is an "@" and Symfony2 will give me this error:

`SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'server' (using password: YES)`

The password is correct, it works everywhere but my Symfony2 project

Comment: Does this user have the good rights on the database?

Comment: @Veve yes, the rights are fine and all connection data are correct

Comment: I suppose this user is correctly defined in parameters.yml too?

Comment: Which format you storing your DB credentials? YAML?

Answer (score 1):

Strings containing non-alphanumeric characters can be escaped using single or double quotes:

```
parameters:
    database_password: "my:pass@word!"
```

If you want to use a string that starts with "@" you must escape it prepending another "@", as stated in [The Book - Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#service-parameters).

So, if your password is "@mypassword":

```
parameters:
    password1: "@mypassword"  # Will not work
    password2: "@@mypassword" # Will work
```

This is required because strings starting with a single "@" are used as service identifiers.