# Error when trying to install symfony 2 composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

After the configuration file `app/config/parameters.yml` NEXT throws me an error, how do I fix ?

install symfony right through composer:

```
Generating autoload files
Would you like to install Acme demo bundle? [y/N] y
Installing the Acme demo bundle.
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
Some parameters are missing. Please provide them.
database_driver (pdo_mysql): 
database_host (127.0.0.1): localhost
database_port (null): 
database_name (symfony): curso_sf
database_user (root): 
database_password (null): @admin1
mailer_transport (smtp): 
mailer_host (127.0.0.1): localhost
mailer_user (null): 
mailer_password (null): 
locale (en): es
secret (ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt): curso_sf!

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]                                  
Invalid type for path "doctrine.dbal.connections.default.password". 
Expected scalar, but got object.  

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]                                                         

An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Comment: it most likely doesn't like the @ symbol in your password

Comment: `@` sign means a service

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the `@` by doubling it `@@` as noted in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#service-parameters):

```
parameters:
    # ...
    database_password : "@@admin1"
```

Thanks to Falc for [his/her answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27061631/2257664).