# Symfony returning error : some parameters are missing. Please provide them

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to install symfony on wamp server,  i'm installing through composer. I tried below command in cmd

```
$ composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition sym2
```

Above command is installing properly symfony latest version on wamp but in the end it returning an error or request for edit something.

`Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml"` file`

I attached cmd screen shot for the reference, can any on guide me how can i solve this issue. I have also update the composer phar before installing symfony.

[image]

Comment: can you check this http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

Comment: @Mit.agile thanks for guide line. One thing is onfusing me, how can i edit `parameters.yml` before installing symfony. becuase installing symfony there is no file

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852616/error-when-trying-to-install-symfony-2-composer

Comment: actually it stops at **database_host** in your cmd if you see .. so now you need to enter your database configuration from cmd itself

Comment: However, i have not worked over **symfony** at all but as a SO user,its my responsibility to search something and give you some output out of my research. Hope it helps you or let me know further if you stuck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## It's not a bug (error), it's a feature.

There's no error, only information.

CMD waits for you to provide values for these missing parameters. Right here in the command line, not directly into `parameters.yml` file.

Currently on the screen it's waiting for you to provide `database_host` or simply press enter to apply default value which is shown in the brackets (`127.0.0.1`).

This is [Interactive Management of the parameters.yml File](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file)

Comment: Wow that's great. Thanks for sharing knowledge +1

Answer (score 0):

You can keep everything by default.

All these parameters can be changed later in the `app/config/parameters.yml` file.